# how to create a round circular frame webgl window scene in website using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want a circular scene instead of the rectangular scene frame, so that just the cube is visible in the website frame. I don't want the whole webpage to show the scene, instead just the cube in a circular frame. Can the scene "`var scene = new THREE.Scene();`" be modified to change the rectangular frame into circular frame? Sorry, if this a stupid question to ask, but didn't find the answer in Google. Please help, I'm just a beginner!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning 3JS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ff3400" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="../three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="detector.js">

        if (Detector.webgl) {
            animate();
        } else {
            var warning = Detector.getWebGLErrorMessage();
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(warning);
        }

    </script>

    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 640px; background: aqua;"></div> 

    <script>

        var container = document.querySelector('#container');

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        scene.add(mesh);
        camera.position.z = 50;

        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffff00);
        /* position the light so it shines on the cube (x, y, z) */
        light.position.set(-15, -10, 30);
        scene.add(light);

        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
        //var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
        controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 )

        var loop = function()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
             controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            mesh.rotation.x += 0.02;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;
            //mesh.rotation.z += 0.1;
        }

        loop();

        renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you could make a square canvas but then use a round stencil buffer so that nothing draws outside of the circle.

Comment: Stencil is not supported by three, compared to the other examples it wouldn't be super trivial (need to get `gl` context, enable stencil, do the correct call) but is a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have a circular canvas/frame buffer, exactly like you cannot have a circular image. This is a kind of general rule of computing.

But like for an image, you can simulate a circular "viewport", and there is MANY different ways to achieve this. For example, by using transparent pixels, or by painting the rectangular background of the image the same color as the background, etc.

Also, i think THREE.js is currently preventing you to understand what you do, because of its automatic functions. You probably better to begin by the beginning, at least to understands the Canvas concept and how WebGL work with it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL

Comment: Uh huh, "preventing" sounds like a pretty bold statement :) I'd argue that it's not preventing since its open source and can be studied. I think it would be just as hard to learn enough webgl to do this as it would be to learn enough three.js and do this some other way. It should also be possible to this with no canvas whatsoever, just using the dom over it. Three will allow you to write a clipping shader, and make a full screen quad much easier than it would with just raw webgl. However, it may not be obvious that you need to do that.

Comment: In this present case, it seem clear to me that deepds14 is "misguided" by THREE.js due to how it automatically creates the canvas element in background process. Something exists, but never appears in the code: the canvas, which is in fact a kind of image. With this simple information (WebGL draws in a kind of image called Canvas), can help to knows what to search for to acheive the goal "circular viewport". Because, the answer begins with how this canvas is composed, displayed, filled, etc.